# How to properly target a .net project into netcoreapp/netstandard?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I have a Class Library that is supposed to be packed into a nuget package. This is its current csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net40;netcoreapp1.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <PackageId>FooPackage</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
    <Authors>Jean Lourenço</Authors>
    <Title>FooPackage</Title>
    <Description>FooPackage</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright 2017</Copyright>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Initial release</PackageReleaseNotes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I created it as a netstandard Class Library and then manually set the `<TargetFrameworks>` to its targets `netstandard1.6;net40;netcoreapp1.0`. Then I use `dotnet pack` to generate my `.nupkg`.

But when I try to use the package in a `netcoreapp`, this happens:

`Package FooPackage 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package FooPackage 1.0.0 supports: net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`

This is the csproj of the consuming app:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The `net452` isn't even referenced directly into the `<TargetFrameworks>`, so I have no idea where that is coming from.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to target those frameworks correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions on [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3994) all I had to do was:

`nuget.exe locals -clear all`

Seems like the nuget kept old references of the package because of the name.